# IF statement - finding more than 1 strings in a range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a if statement to do some action for 3 scenarios if the .text is "A", "B" and Or("A","B"). 
I am facing problem when the range have both "A" and "B" and I just wanna know what is the best way to find both strings in the range I am looking.

`ElseIf Master.Range("V13:V18").Text Like "A" Or Master.Range("V13:V18").Text Like "B" Then`

*edited the data set for clarity on the 3 scenario

```
case 1    case 2    case 3
1 A        1 B       1 A
2 A        2 B       2 A
3 A        3 B       3 A
4 A        4 B       4 B
5 A        5 B       5 A
6 A        6 B       6 B
```

This is part of the code which I have written.

```
If Master.Range("V13:V18").Text Like "A" Then
do something..
ElseIf Master.Range("V13:V18").Text Like "B" Then
do something..
ElseIf Master.Range("V13:V18").Text Like "A" Or Master.Range("V13:V18").Text Like "B" Then
do something..
```

Comment: Ain't your 1st 2 cases conflict with the Third one ? If 1st case is true then 3rd is also true, if 2nd is true then 3rd is also true.

Comment: Your Example doesn't even have any `AB`

Comment: yes, currently it is not working as intended. I want it to search for both “A” and “B” concurrently

Comment: Can you share the Screenshot of data and what you would like to see as result ?

Comment: I have edited the question with the data set

Comment: You could create helper column with concatenated "case 1" and "case 2" columns and search in there

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub Test()

Dim A As Long, B As Long
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master")
    A = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("V13:V18"), "A")
    B = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("V13:V18"), "B")
    If A = .Range("V13:V18").Cells.Count Then
        MsgBox "All A"
    ElseIf B = .Range("V13:V18").Cells.Count Then
        MsgBox "All B"
    ElseIf A + B = .Range("V13:V18").Cells.Count Then
        MsgBox "Both A and B"
    Else
        MsgBox "Other values too"
    End If
End With

End Sub
```